# How do I delete rows I don't need in dataframe pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to delete a certain row where both the ZIPCODE and AV_LAND values would be deleted. For instance, I want to delete row 1 and 2. How would I do that? In addition, I want to reset the index once I delete all the rows I don't need.

```
ZIPCODE AV_LAND
0   02108   2653506
1   02109   5559661
2   02110   11804931
3   02134  4333212
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use drop:

```
df.drop([1, 2]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out: 
    ZIPCODE  AV_LAND
0     02108  2653506
1     02134  4333212
```

This is not an inplace operation so if you want to change the original DataFrame you need to assign it back: `df = df.drop([1, 2]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Also, are the 1 and 2 representing the indexes or row numbers?

Comment: They are the index labels.